# What is the correct way to return an image from a C function?

Tags: c

I'm new to C trying to understand the basics.

I am wanting to call a function that creates and returns a jpeg image.

In some other language like Python you would just put the return value from the function into a variable. C obviously does not work that way.

What is the correct way then for one function to ask another for a jpeg image and to receive back that image, which is of an unknown size?

Is the correct way to create a struct that defines a pointer to a buffer and a length, and then to set a variable outside the scope of both functions, so that both functions can access the data?

Presumably I also need to properly free the memory used inside the makeimg function via  `tjFree(&_compressedImage);`

I copied the code for this function from somewhere on the net. It creates a jpeg function.  I want to get the resulting jpeg back.

```
static void makeimg() {
        const int JPEG_QUALITY = 75;
        const int COLOR_COMPONENTS = 3;
        int _width = 1920;
        int _height = 1080;
        long unsigned int _jpegSize = 0;
        unsigned char* _compressedImage = NULL; //!< Memory is allocated by tjCompress2 if _jpegSize == 0
        unsigned char buffer[_width*_height*COLOR_COMPONENTS]; //!< Contains the uncompressed image
        tjhandle _jpegCompressor = tjInitCompress();
        tjCompress2(_jpegCompressor, buffer, _width, 0, _height, TJPF_RGB,
                  &_compressedImage, &_jpegSize, TJSAMP_444, JPEG_QUALITY,
                  TJFLAG_FASTDCT);
        tjDestroy(_jpegCompressor);
        //to free the memory allocated by TurboJPEG (either by tjAlloc(),
        //or by the Compress/Decompress) after you are done working on it:
        tjFree(&_compressedImage);
}
```

Any guidance on a good approach to take appreciated.

I am a beginner with C (experienced with Python), so if you could please explain as much as possible about your response it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this. I prefer the following:

```
/*
 * Makes an image and returns the length
 * returns < 0 on error
 *
 * Call as follows:
 *  char *image ;
 *  int len = make_image( &image );
 *  if (len < 0) { /* Process error code */ }
*/
int makeImage(void **image) {
    unsigned char *_image ;
    int length ;
    /* Create image and set the length of buffer in length variable */
    /* Return the image */
    *image = _image ;
    return length;
}
```

If you do not need multiple error codes, setting image parameter to null and checking for it may be enough.

Comment: Beginner C question: why is the argument type ** which I understand to be a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: @DukeDougal The double pointer is used to *return* a pointer via this parameter. This happens in the line `*image = _image;`: The double pointer is dereferenced, and the simple pointer behind it is written to. If the returned value were an `int`, the argument would be of type `int*`, but since the returned value is itself a pointer `void*`, the type of the argument must be a double pointer `void**`.

Comment: Btw, it's not a good idea to use `void*` like this. It makes type-checking impossible. If you want to keep the contents of the data structure private, just do a forward declaration `typedef struct Image Image;` and use that for the pointer type `int makeImage(Image** out_image);`.

Comment: @cmaster Agree. Though in this case what is being returned is in-effect only a buffer. May be OK.

Comment: OK so am I correct in understanding that the double pointer is the mechanism for when we wish to pass a pointer as an argument i.e. to get a pointer into a function, the function takes a pointer to a pointer which is derefenced inside the function.  This then is the mechanism via which both the calling and function and the called function can both use refer to the same pointer?

Comment: @DukeDougal You pass a pointer to pointer to allow the called method to allocate memory and return to the calling method. This happens in case where the size of the buffer is not known to the caller method.

Comment: @DakshinamurthyKarra why can this not be done with an ordinary pointer? Why is a double pointer required?

Comment: @DukeDougal because C supports call by value. Setting the value in called method does not change the value in the caller method